# Why Generated Active Record Query dosen't run in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am having a code that runs a delayed job that generates a report and then sends in an email here :
`InstancesExportJob.perform_later(instances: instances, custom_field_key: options[:custom_field_key],tag_columns: options[:tags],user: User.current,report_url: report_url)`

where `instances` is a generated active record query that is generated by another class this code fails and gives the following error: `ActiveJob::SerializationError:Unsupported argument type: ActiveRecord::Relation`.
where the first operation that is done on `instances` is a `map` function call.

but changing the code to this makes it work fine:
`InstancesExportJob.perform_later(instances: instances.to_a, custom_field_key: options[:custom_field_key],tag_columns: options[:tags],user: User.current,report_url: report_url)`.

I am confused as running the code without delayed jobs works fine.

Am using `rails 4.2` and `sidekiq`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with `sidekiq` as it do not allow a wide variety of parameter types and having the instance as an active record relation made the whole thing raise an error